# Difference between もうひとつの, 別の and ほかの

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I read [this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62730/how-to-say-when-this-kanji-appears-inside-of-anther-kanji-we-will-give-it-the-me) in another post:

> でも貝のかんじに**もうひとつ**のいみをつけます。
>   But we will assign another meaning to the kanji 貝.

Putting aside any other problems with this sentence, I feel that もう一つ isn't the right word to use for 'another' in this context. I may of course be wrong, but I would have gone with 別の or 他の instead, but I can't explain why (maybe because I'm talking nonsense).

Anyway, I'm now wondering what the difference is between もうひとつ, 別 and 他 when used to mean 'another'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the difference is subtle here.

もうひとつ means *another* by way of meaning *one other* or *one more*.

別 can mean *another* by way of meaning *different.*

他 is probably the truest sense of the word *another,* but there are cases where you'd use one of the other two in a more natural context.

In the sense of the given phrase, I think all three utterances work equally well:

> でも貝のかんじにもうひとつのいみをつけます。
>   でも貝のかんじに別｛べつ｝のいみをつけます。
>   でも貝のかんじに他｛ほか｝のいみをつけます。

If もうひとつ was chosen here it was merely because it is probably the first of the three phrases to be introduced in a textbook.